# How can I disable click action on SWF Object?

Tags: jquery, flash, swfobject

I'm looking for a way to go to a URL when clicking on a SWF OBJECT.

I have tried wrapping an HREF around an OBJECT and I find the HREF opens in one window and another window opens and gives a 404 e.g. http://www.mysite.co.uk/undefined

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
<object width="300" height="250" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="element2.swf" id="swf3a0a2" style="visibility: visible;"><param name="wmode" value="window"><param name="menu" value="false"><param name="quality" value="high"><param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></object>
</a>
```

I'm wondering if the SWF has a paramater set for passing in a URL. Is there as standard way of doing this? How could I test?

If it doesn't have URL parameter can I disable the OBJECT click action? I could add a text HREF below the object. I this but it didn't work.

```
$("object").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe JavaScript and HTML are able to interact with the contents of an SWF object, but you could overlay (not wrap) the object with a transparent DIV containing a link - or just a link if you prefer. This would disable any interactivity with the SWF object though - depending on your needs this may be acceptable.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I had seen this suggestion but unfortunately it's not going to work for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: place a transparent HTML element over the SWF and set a click handler on it, or modify the SWF itself.  You can't simply wrap the SWF in `<a>` -- the SWF is being played by Flash Player and is not a normal DOM element. It doesn't follow the same rules as DOM elements.